# Unable to get Regression line and the variance bounds in Seaborn pairplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am unable to get regression line and the variance bounds around it while plotting `seaborn.pairplot` with `kind=reg` as shown in the examples at http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html

```
import pandas pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
# Preparing random dataFrame with two colums, viz., random x and lag-1 values 
lst1 = list(np.random.rand(10000))
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1':lst1})
df['x2'] = df['x1'].shift(1)
df = df[df['x2'] > 0]
# Plotting now
pplot = sns.pairplot(df, kind="reg")
pplot.set(ylim=(min(df['x1']), max(df['x1'])))
pplot.set(xlim=(min(df['x1']), max(df['x1'])))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The regression line is there, you just don't see it, because it's hidden by the unnaturally high number of points in the plot.

[image]

So let's reduce the number of points and you'll see the regression as expected.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Preparing random dataFrame with two colums, viz., random x and lag-1 values 
lst1 = list(np.random.rand(100))
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1':lst1})
df['x2'] = df['x1'].shift(1)
df = df[df['x2'] > 0]
# Plotting now
pplot = sns.pairplot(df, kind="reg")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnes. This is just the sample data. Somehow for real data (which is 10s of thousands but does not fill the full panel) I am still unable to see these lines.

Comment: Well, the reason for not seeing the line in the code from the question is clearly the number of points. Of course we can only help here by working with the code that you show us. If your case is different, try to find a [mcve] of the issue, which actually helps you solving your real problem. Else, we cannot do much to help.

Comment: can I add display the r and p values in these pairplots (like in jointplot)??